# Applying Jquery to unknown amount of numbered IDs

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I know next to nothing about JQuery, and find most of my solutions on Stackoverflow, so I'm hoping there is an answer to my (probably noob as well as first ever "so.com") question. I am trying to apply a jquery script to an unknown number of numbered IDs. I could reference every single ID from id-1 to id-1000 and hope I never need more or I could somehow reference id-n, in which case it would apply to any ID with a number at the end.

Here's the code I have:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function (){jQuery("#pika-[any integer]").PikaCho...
```

Which should affect:

```
<ul id="pika-1"> or <ul id="pika-329"> or <ul id="pika-[any integer]">
```

How would I go about getting this done?

(For clarity's sake, this is inside a Drupal template.php file to affect a pikachoose gallery display. Not that I think that would make a difference.)

Comment: Could you apply a class to the `<ul>` and select on the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('ul[id^="pika-"]')` will select all ul's that have an id starting with "pika-"

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting this as well, the only drawback is if he has `pika-123a` but doesn't want to select that, its a fringe case but meh.

Comment: It would still work for that as it starts with "pika-" and doesn't care what comes afterword. He could add another condition as well.

Comment: Yeah, what Im saying is if he has something like `pika-hi-there` but yeah I agree :) was just pointing out the fringe case.

Comment: Then we'd be looking at regex :)

Comment: @BillBarry How does a class selector compare? Assuming, of course, they can modify the HTML to add a unique class to every element.

Comment: $('a.classname') is about as fast as querySelectorAll. If you can use getElementsByClassName tough...  http://jsperf.com/jquery-id-startswith/3

Comment: Thank you so much, @JayBlanchard, that work! I made a small change (the original version wouldn't fire).

I changed `$('ul[id^="pika-"]')` to `$('[id^="pika-"]')` and it worked like a charm! Awesome!

Thanks also to everyone else for their input. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Also wanted to point out this is one line with JS not requiring jQuery overhead.

```
document.querySelectorAll("ul[id^=pika-]");​
```

And a solution to take care of some of the edge cases.

**[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/cqrkK/)**

```
var elements = [];

[].forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("ul[id^=pika-]"),
    function(el){
        var check = /[0-9]$/;
        if(el.id.match(check)){
           elements.push(el); 
        }
     }
);
```

Also edited Jay Blanchard's js perf, and added qsa with the `ul` identifier, qsa outperforms jQuery (surprise)

http://jsperf.com/jquery-id-startswith/2
​

Comment: The only issue with that is that it will not work on IE7 and below.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('ul').filter('[id^=”pika-”]')
```

Comment: According to jsperf on Firefox 11, Jay's answer is better.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-id-startswith/2 actually added qsa, and it performs the best :).

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
jQuery("[id^=pika]").pikaCho
```

so every element with id starting with "pika" will be affected.